# How do I get controls in sub components recognized in a parent form? (angular2 rc3)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I just upgraded the application I am working on to the latest version of Angular 2 (rc3), Router & Forms (0.1.1). I am now trying to get the forms converted to the latest library & best practices. I am using [Angular IO docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) to try and complete this.

I can get the form to work if I do something like this:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
  <input type="text" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="model.firstName" required />
</form>
```

But I have my form split out into multiple components - there are 4 sections on the page so I have one component representing each section, and each section has somewhere between 5-10 input fields of various types.

So my code is essentially:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
  <section-1 [(model)]="model"></section-1>
  <section-2 [(model)]="model"></section-2>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

But the form does not add the controls from child components into the form's controls list. What is the best way to go about this? I could put a form in each subcomponent that tracks its own valid state and use the parent to manage the 4 different valid states 'manually', but it seems like there should be a better way.

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Hi Dan, did you work this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a model variable in parent to represent your child component that may have multiple fields, then the child component will start to act as a form control in parent form after it properly implements ControlValueAccessor interface which tells Angular 2 how to propagate values between model and view. Look for third example in [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1121101/Angular-custom-component-with-validation-for-ban)